# R accuracy function throws window.default error on timeseries test set

Tags: r, time-series

I split my timeseries var to train-test set by this code:

```
df_train <- df %>%
  filter(dt >= as.Date("2019-01-01") &  dt <= as.Date("2020-02-29"))

df_test <- df %>%
  filter(dt >= as.Date("2020-03-01") &  dt <= as.Date("2020-03-12"))

ts_train_tmp <- ts(data=df_train$new_user_cnt, frequency = 7)
ts_train <- diff(ts_train_tmp, 1)

ts_test_tmp <- ts(data=df_test$new_user_cnt, frequency = 7)
ts_test <- diff(ts_test_tmp, 1)
```

Then, I did the train & test by:

```
f_snaive <- snaive(ts_train, h=12)
accuracy(f_snaive, ts_test)
```

But the accuracy function above throws this error:

```
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
```

I don't understand why it returns this error. My train set is between Jan 2019 to Feb 2020 and the test set is 1st March 2020 to 12th March 2020.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct the `ts_train` and `ts_test` objects, you throw away the date information, so they are both set to start on the same date.

I suggest you use the `fable` package instead of the `forecast` package for daily data. It uses `tsibble` rather than `ts` objects. Most of the same modelling and forecasting methods are available. Here is some code showing how to do the same thing you are attempting, but using `tsibble` and `fable` rather than `ts` objects.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

df <- data.frame(
    dt = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "day", length = 450),
    new_user_cnt = rnorm(450)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = dt) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = difference(new_user_cnt)
  )
df
#> # A tsibble: 450 x 3 [1D]
#>    dt         new_user_cnt   diff
#>    <date>            <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 2019-01-01       0.523  NA    
#>  2 2019-01-02       1.52    0.999
#>  3 2019-01-03      -2.51   -4.03 
#>  4 2019-01-04      -0.612   1.90 
#>  5 2019-01-05      -0.125   0.486
#>  6 2019-01-06       0.410   0.536
#>  7 2019-01-07      -1.30   -1.71 
#>  8 2019-01-08      -0.0844  1.22 
#>  9 2019-01-09      -0.239  -0.154
#> 10 2019-01-10      -1.44   -1.20 
#> # … with 440 more rows

df_train <- df %>%
  filter(dt >= as.Date("2019-01-01") & dt <= as.Date("2020-02-29"))

f_snaive <- df_train %>%
  model(
    mod1 = SNAIVE(diff)
  ) %>%
  forecast(h=12)

accuracy(f_snaive, df)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 9
#>   .model .type      ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE   ACF1
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 mod1   Test  -0.0379  2.08  1.72  117.  164.  1.17 -0.412
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is working. Thanks so much for helping and also for your online book Sir!